# Is it Legal to listen to Air Traffic Control Frequencies in the USA on a computer for entertainment?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airport

like listening to scanners an radio frequencies for entertainment and i make it a game because i use a online flight tracker and try to find that aircraft. Is it legal?

Comment: Just to be clear, while doing this *is* legal in the USA, it is not necessarily legal in *all* countries. Having said that, whether the legality is practically enforceable or not is another question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is legal in the US, and you can listen to audio streams on websites such as https://www.liveatc.net